# Mobile Build in Unity works differently from Unity Editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

We use the latest version of Unity.
We have encountered a weird issue while building the mobile game build.
This is a 2D Platformer Game.
 1. In debug mode, our enemies attack the player properly using proper hitting animations and dealing damage.
 2. when we build the game into either mobile version or desktop version
    our enemies act as if they have the aggresive AI script working,
    however their hitting animation doesn't play/show but the player still takes
    damage(the enemies just stand next to the player, and the hitting animation is not shown. Just the animation of the player getting hurt is shown)

Is there something we can do to fix this?

Comment: Any possibilities for race conditions? (E.g. dependencies on the order of Awake calls)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems impossible to solve your issue without knowing your Animator setups, prefab configuration, scripts that are supposed to run the animations, etc.

Comment: Are your builds stripped? Perhaps the Animator classes are stripped away.

Comment: Hi derHugo and aalmigthy, thank you for your instant replies. Will check on the race conditions and animator classes being stripped away as you mentioned, and revert.